# Проблема с click, не сворачивается блок, когда кликаешь вне кнопки

Tags: javascript, jquery

Проблема такая, при нажатии на кнопку, показывает список, но он не убирается, если кликнуть вне блока, и еще приходится нажимать на другую кнопку два раза, после того как нажмешь на предыдущую кнопку.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var opened = false;

  $('.btn-list').click(function(e) {
    if (!opened) {
      $(this).children('ul').stop(false, false).slideDown('slow');
    } else {
      $(this).children('ul').stop(false, false).slideUp('');
    }
    opened = !opened;
  });
});
```

```css
#nav {
  margin: 30px;
}
#nav li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
}
#nav>li>ul {
  display: none;
  margin-left: -40px;
}
#nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  background: green;
}
#nav > li > ul > li {
  position: relative;
}
#nav > li > ul > li > ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 73%;
  top: 0;
}
#nav > li > ul > li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul id="nav">

    <li class="btn-list">
      <a href="#">Магазин</a>
      <ul class="t">
        <li><a href="#">Домашня сторiнка</a>
        </li>
        <li class="r">
          <a href="#">Office</a>
          <ul class="add-block">
            <li><a href="#">Windows</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Windows</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Windows</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Windows</a>
        </li>

      </ul>

    </li>
    <li class="btn-list">
      <a href="#">Продукты</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Програмне забезпечення та служби</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Пристрої та Xbox</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Для бiзнесу</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Для IT-фахiвцiв i розробникiв</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Освiта</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Пiдримка</a>
    </li>


  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var menu = $('#nav');
  $('.btn-list', menu).on('click', function() {
    var opened = $(this).hasClass('opened');
    $('.btn-list.opened', menu).not($(this)).trigger('click');
    if (!opened) {
      $(this).children('ul').stop(false, false).slideDown('slow');
    } else {
      $(this).children('ul').stop(false, false).slideUp('');
    }
    $(this).toggleClass('opened', !opened);
  });
});
```

Как-то так.... Хотя и костыль )

В вашем случае: 1 - обработчик лучше вешать на ссылку, 2 - судя по коду, при клике не на кнопку - ничего происходить не будет. 3 - переменная opened - при первом клике стала true и при клике на другой пункт меню работает вот это

```
else {
  $(this).children('ul').stop(false, false).slideUp('');
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, работает)

Answer (score 1):

По клику показываем или скрываем список и прекращаем передачу текущего события (*stopPropagation*). При клике по любой другой области только скрываем.

```js
$('.list').click(function(e) {
    list = $(this).children('ul');
    list.stop().slideToggle();
    e.stopPropagation();

    $(document).click(function() {
        $('.list').children('ul').slideUp();
    });
});
```

```css
#nav { margin: 30px; }

#nav li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
}

#nav > li > ul {
  display: none;
  margin-left: -40px;
}

#nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  background: green;
}

#nav > li > ul > li { position: relative; }
#nav > li > ul > li > ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 73%;
  top: 0;
}

#nav > li > ul > li:hover > ul { display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id='nav'>
  <li class='list'>
    <a href='#'>Магазин</a>
      <ul class='t'>
        <li><a href="#">Домашня сторiнка</a></li>
        <li class="r">
          <a href="#">Office</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>

  <li class='list'>
    <a href='#'>Продукты</a>
      <ul class='t'>
        <li><a href="#">Програмне забезпечення та служби</a></li>
        <li class="r">
          <a href="#">Пристрої та Xbox</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Баг - если открыть одновременно оба пункта, скроется только последний, первый нужно будет тыкнуть чтобы скрыть

Comment: Но я, мечту свою лелея, решил проблему гениально: скрывать всё сразу

Comment: странно, но ваш код у меня не работает, здесь работает хорошо, у меня никак не реагирует

Comment: @OlegKisleakov, я сменил класс у селектора с `.btn-list` на `.list`, может в этом дело?

Comment: нет, это я изменил, вставлял ваш код и все равно

Comment: @OlegKisleakov, консоль на что-нибудь ругается?

Comment: нет, там все в порядке, а может быть проблема в библиотеке, может ее лучше скачать?

Comment: @OlegKisleakov, можно скрин кода? Я только что заменил библиотеку на 1.9.0 и результат тот же. Мне интересно в чём причина

Comment: прикрепил, смотрите

Comment: посмотрели? не знаете в чем проблема?

Comment: @OlegKisleakov, странно, даже скрипт перенёс в документ. Вот файл для теста [index.html](https://yadi.sk/d/y6TLckOBtChQv)

Comment: посмотрел в другом редакторе кода, все работает, возможно, это из-за программы, даже не знаю, что думать

Comment: @OlegKisleakov, значит пока останется тайной. Я пишу в Notepad++

Comment: у вас работает, переместил значит  библиотеку и код скрипта за body, и все заработало) магия что ли)

Comment: спасибо тебе за помощь, выручил)

Comment: @OlegKisleakov, если скрипт был в body, скорее всего какой-то обработчик не успевал найти элемент

Comment: он был в head,  увидел как вы сделали и решил попробовать, сработало

Comment: @OlegKisleakov, ну тогда всё правильно. Сначало грузился скрипт, после его загрузки ещё небыло никаких `.btn-list`, он ничего не нашёл и обработчики не работали. Сначало нужно грузить все элементы, потом скрипты. Ну или если хочешь помещать скрипты в заголовок, нужно помещать весь скрипт в `window.onload = function() { ... }`, это событие на загрузку всего документа вместе с изображенииями или jquery `$(function() { ... });`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуте перехватить на `focusout`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  

  $('.btn-list').click(function(e) {  
    if($(this).children('ul').is(":visible")){
     $(this).children('ul').stop(false, false).slideUp('');
    }else{
      $(this).children('ul').stop(false, false).slideDown('slow'); 
    }
  });
  $(".btn-list").focusout(function(){
     $(this).children('ul').stop(false, false).slideUp('');
  })
});
```

```css
#nav {
  margin: 30px;
}
#nav li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
}
#nav>li>ul {
  display: none;
  margin-left: -40px;
}
#nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  background: green;
}
#nav > li > ul > li {
  position: relative;
}
#nav > li > ul > li > ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 73%;
  top: 0;
}
#nav > li > ul > li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul id="nav">

    <li class="btn-list">
      <a href="#">Магазин</a>
      <ul class="t">
        <li><a href="#">Домашня сторiнка</a>
        </li>
        <li class="r">
          <a href="#">Office</a>
          <ul class="add-block">
            <li><a href="#">Windows</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Windows</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Windows</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Windows</a>
        </li>

      </ul>

    </li>
    <li class="btn-list">
      <a href="#">Продукты</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Програмне забезпечення та служби</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Пристрої та Xbox</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Для бiзнесу</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Для IT-фахiвцiв i розробникiв</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Освiта</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Пiдримка</a>
    </li>


  </ul>
</nav>
```

не надо никаких костылей...

Comment: После открытия нельзя снова скрыть на эту же кнопку